# Load android instagram page on iOS (swift)?

Tags: android, ios, swift, instagram, user-agent

I need to load instagram page on iOS like android does.

Yes, I tried to change "User-Agent" but this fix works on simulator only and on real device Instagram still somehow understands that it is iOS. Example of url:

```
let baseUrl = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/"
```

How to solve this issue? And how instagram in general figures out that it is iOS device?

Code:

```
    let baseUrl = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/"
    let url = URL(string: baseUrl)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.setValue("Instagram 27.0.0.7.97 Android (24/7.0; 380dpi; 1080x1920; OnePlus; ONEPLUS A3010; OnePlus3T; qcom; en_US)", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
    webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Comment: Please, provide the code you tried so far. I tried to run the request with the sniffer. [Here it is](https://pastebin.com/CF3Kcj7U). Only the `user-agent` field tells that it's iOS

Comment: @fewlinesofcode added code. To assume that it is "android" you should run this request for any web view - it mentions "app store" in the top banner if it find out that it is iOS. Otherwise you see something related to android. Works on simulator only!